# What is this aeroplane - not a Blackbird?

Tags: aircraft-identification, feature-identification

What is the aeroplane in the first image?

I noticed this photo in a youtube clip, and at first glance thought it was a three-engine Blackbird SR-71, but it appears to be a single-seater.

[image]

The text and audio does not reveal what the photo is of.

> youtube.com/watch?v=nagVeYYt13s#t=10m41s

Some googling suggests that is a D-21 drone atop a M-21, and wikipedia has this somewhat-unhelpful photo.

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cc/Lockheed_M-21_%26_D-21_drone.jpg/1200px-Lockheed_M-21_%26_D-21_drone.jpg]

Comment: That photo is from the Boeing Museum of Flight, in Seattle, WA.  Detailed description here: http://www.museumofflight.org/Exhibits/blackbird

Comment: @abelenky Nice find - thank you.  Shows a more useful photo,

Comment: The aircraft in the video is an M-21 and is actually a two place aircraft. One Pilot and one Launch Control Officer.

Comment: indeed. The rear windows are visible, albeit difficult to see due to the quality of the image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The large aircraft **is** the Lockheed M-21 (which was developed from the [Lockheed A-12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_A-12), the same aircraft that the SR-71 was developed from), and the smaller aircraft is the D-21 drone.

The wikipedia article on the [D-21](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_D-21) has a lot of information.

Comment: Deep Space thanks.  Apparently some editor has taken a rather amoeboid response to my answer. FYI the MD remark was humor!

Answer (score 5):

It’s called an M-21 Blackbird.  It’s a derivative of the A-12/SR-71 family of aircraft modified for launching a supersonic ramjet powered reconnaissance drone called the D-21 (“M” designation standing for “Mothership” and “D” standing for “Daughtership”).  The program never worked out and destroyed one aircraft which the drone collided with during separation and launch tests.  The D-21 drones made several more flights, albeit by launching from a B-52 bomber using a rocket booster to accelerate it to Mach 3, but all but one flight failed, either crashing over enemy territory or sinking in the ocean either due to vehicle or telemetry failure.  The last known M-21 Blackbird is on display at Seattle’s Museum of Flight at KBFI.